# Telegram bot does nothing after one reply

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am new to python and trying to create a conversation bot on telegram that asks the user for their gender and age. However, my bot does not do anything after getting the age of the user. 
My functions for the gender and the age:

```
def gender(bot, update):
# Get gender from user
user = update.message.from_user
logger.info("Gender of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
update.message.reply_text(
    "<TEXT>",
reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

def age(bot, update):
# Get age from user
user = update.message.from_user
logger.info("Age of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
update.message.reply_text(
        "<TEXT>"
)
return ConversationHandler.END

def skip_age(bot, update):
# /skip command
user = update.message.from_user
logger.info("User %s did not specify age", user.first_name)
update.message.reply_text(
    "<TEXT>"
)
return ConversationHandler.END
```

The command handler and message handler in the main function:

```
 conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('chat', chat)],

    states={
        GENDER: [RegexHandler('^(Boy|Girl|Other)$', gender)],

        AGE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, age),
            CommandHandler('skip', skip_age)]
    },

    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)

dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

The log of the bot(Renamed the token in the log):

```
2018-09-30 21:20:33,977 - __main__ = INFO - Gender of Jan: Boy
2018-09-30 21:29:00,826 - telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool = WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool object at 0x7fafec6b5ef0>, 'Connect timed out. (connect timeout=5.0)')': /bot<TOKEN>/getUpdates
```

Link to py file for the whole code: https://github.com/TryingOutSomething/testing/blob/master/testing.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing adding your functions to the handlers.

At line 109, you have this:

```
# Help command
help_command = CommandHandler('help', help)
dispatcher.add_handler(help_command)
```

That's to add the function `help` as a handler, to handle commands. What you need is to add your functions as handlers too, you can just copy paste that those lines and replace `'help'` with the thing you write to your bot, and `help` with the name of the function you want it to be.

Example:

```
# Ask my age command
the_age_command = CommandHandler('age', age)
dispatcher.add_handler(the_age_command)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it made me realise where my mistake is! It turns out that I did not return AGE after the gender function